# If $2x + 3y$ is multiple of $17$, then $9x + 5y$ is multiple of $17$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, integers

I want proof that:

> If $2x + 3y$ is multiple of $17$, then $9x + 5y$ is multiple of $17$.

My attempt:

By the Bezout's theorem, how $mdc(2, 3) = 1$, exists $r, s \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$2r + 3s = 1$$

Then, consider the set

$$\mathcal{A} = \lbrace (r,s) \in \mathbb{Z} : 2r + 3s = 1 \rbrace$$

By the hypothesis, $2x + 3y = 17k$, for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Observe that for all $(r, s) \in \mathcal{A}$,
$$(2r + 3s)17k = 2(17kr) + 3(17ks) = 17k$$
Thus, we can consider that for some $(r, s) \in \mathcal{A}$
$$17kr = x$$
and
$$17ks = y$$

Hence, $17|9x + 5y = 17(9kr + 5ks)$.

I'd like to know if my attempt is correct.
Someone can help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: It is not true that $17$ necessarily divides $x$ and $y$. Take for example $3\cdot 3+2\cdot 4=17$ (i.e. $x=3$, $y=4$).

Comment: @Milten Thank you!!

Comment: $2x+3y\equiv 0 \pmod{17}\iff 2x \equiv -3y\pmod{17} \iff 13\times 2 x \equiv -13\times 3 y \pmod{17}$ noting that $13$ is coprime to $17$.  Continuing: $13\times 2 x \equiv -13\times 3 y\pmod{17}\iff 26 x \equiv -39y\pmod{17}\iff 9x \equiv -5y\pmod{17}$

Comment: This is essentially a dupe of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/724884/242), except for the attempt checking. Please read the answers there.

Comment: And it is a exact dupe of [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/876542/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$3(9x+5y)-5(2x+3y) =17x$$

Since $3$and $17$ are relatively prime if $2x+3y$ Is a multiple of $17$ so is $9x+5y$

Comment: It was the other way around in the question. (No biggie of course).

Comment: Thanks for your attention I fixed it

Comment: Worth *explicit* emphasis: the coefficients are chosen in order to *eliminate* $\,y,\ $ and the argument requires $\, 17\mid 3n\,\Rightarrow\, 17\mid n\ $ by Euclid's lemma, or directly  $\ 17\mid n = 6(3n)-17n\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

As remarked. that type of argument doesn't work. Instead $\rm\color{#0a0}{scale}$ it to match-up $\rm\color{#c00}{coef's}$
 of $x$

Hint: $\ \bmod 17\!:\ \  \color{#c00}{9}x\!+\!5y\,\equiv \color{#0a0}{{-}4}\,(\color{#c00}2x\!+\!3y)\equiv -4(0)\equiv 0$

We employ the scaling factor $\,\color{#0a0}{-4}\equiv  \color{#c00}{\dfrac{9}2}\equiv \dfrac{\!-8}2\,$ to *equalize* the coef's on $\,x,\,$ via $\,(9/2)2 = 9$

**Remark** $ $ It's a perfect scaling since $\,\dfrac{9}2\equiv \dfrac{5}3,\ $ by $\,9\cdot 3\equiv 2\cdot 5,\,$ i.e. the scaling also equalizes the coef's on $\,y,\,$ by $\,(5/3)3 = 5.\,$ Over any field -  we can employ such cross products to test for scale equivalence of linear forms - just as we use line *slopes* to test equivalence of lines (through  origin).

Alternatively we could take a linear combination of the forms that *eliminates* $x$ or $y$ (but this involves scaling *both* forms so we need to further argue that scaling by an integer coprime to $17$ doesn't affect divisibility by $17$, e.g. see my comment on Mohammad's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not correct since $9$ and $5$ never really come into play.
But you may notice that $\frac{9}{2}=9(2)^{-1}$ and $\frac{5}{3}=5(3)^{-1}$ are the same class $\!\!\pmod{17}$, namely $13$.
So $2x+3y\equiv 0\pmod{17}$ implies $13(2x+3y)\equiv 0\pmod{17}$, i.e. $9x+5y\equiv 0\pmod{17}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof attempt is not valid. The problem is that the original statement you are trying to prove is a statement about *all* pairs $x,y$ that satisfy $17 \mid (2x + 3y)$, but your argument just produces a *particular* pair $x,y$ that satisfies this. It is true that if you make sure $x,y$ are both multiples of $17$, then both $2x+3y$ and also $9x+5y$ will be multiples of $17$, but your argument doesn't say anything about pairs $x,y$ that satisfy that $2x+3y$ is a multiple of $17$ even though $x,y$ are not.

Answer (score 1):

If $2x+3y\equiv 0\pmod{17}$ then $$0\equiv2x+3y\equiv36x+20y=4(9x+5y)\equiv0\pmod{17}$$

Since $(4,17)=1$, the result follows.