# Let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that $2x+3y$ is a multiple of $17$. Show that $9x+5y$ must also be a multiple of $17$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that $2x+3y$ is a multiple of $17$. Show that $9x+5y$ must also be a multiple of $17$.

So $2x+3y \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$. Adding $7x$ and $2y$ we have that $9x+5y \equiv 7x+2y \pmod{17}$, thus we would need to show that $7x+2y \equiv0 \pmod{17}$.

How should I approach this? I cannot see to be able to show the last congruence...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to just work directly with the original number.

Note that

$$ 17x + 17y - 4(2x+3y) = 9x + 5y.$$

Everything on the left is a multiple on 17, and hence so is the number on the right.

Comment: $17x$ and $17y$ are clearly multiples of $17$, but $17$ doesn't divide $4(2x+3y)$?

Comment: $2x+3y$ is a multiple of 17 by assumption, so $4(2x+3y)$ is also a multiple of 17.

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel The key idea is to scale $2x+3y$ by a factor $\,c\,$ to get $\,9x+5y,\,$  For that we need $\,2c\equiv 9\equiv -8\iff c\equiv -4.\,$ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3419242/242) for more. At asahay: please try to resist quickly answering FAQs before there is a chance for dupes to be located.