# Modular Arithmetic Congruences

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can someone please help me on this problem in modular Arithmetic Congruences I ran into this problem on aops alcumus

If $3x+7\equiv 2\pmod{16}$, then $2x+11$ is congruent $\pmod{16}$ to what integer between $0$ and $15$, inclusive?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $6 \cdot 3 \equiv 2 \bmod 16$

Comment: i.e. as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3419242/242), scale the first congruence by $\,\dfrac{\color{#0a0}2}{\color{#c00}3}\equiv \dfrac{18}3\equiv 6\,$ to change the coef of $x$ from $\,\color{#c00}3\,$ to $\,\color{#0a0}2\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Solve the initial congruence $\;3x\equiv -5\mod 16$. As $3$ is coprime to $16$, it is invertible $\bmod16$, and the inverse is deduced from a Bézout's relation $\;3u+16v=1$, which shows the inverse of $3\bmod 16$ is the congruence class of $u$.